# About Weak Feller property of a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory

I have trouble understanding an example in the book "Markov chains and stochastic stability" by R.L. Tweedie.

A probability transition kernel $P$ acts on bounded functions as
$$Ph(x)=\int P(x,dy)h(y)$$
Let $X$ be a locally compact, separable, metric space and let $\mathcal{C}(X)$ be the set of bounded continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The Weak Feller property is that the probability transition kernel $P$ maps $\mathcal{C}(X)$ to $\mathcal{C}(X)$.

Example: Nonlinear state model $NSS(F)$. The Markov chain $\{X_n\}$ is defined as
$$X_k=F(X_{k-1},W_k)$$ for some smooth function $F:X\times \mathbb{R}^p\to X$ where $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $W_k$ are random variables defined on $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Proof: By definition $x\to F(x,w)$ is continuous for each fixed $w\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus whenever $h:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and continuous, $h\circ F(x,w)$ is also bounded and continuous for each $w\in \mathbb{R}$. It follows from the Dominated convergence theorem that
\begin{align}
Ph(x) &= E[h(F(x,w))] \\
&= \int \Gamma(dw)h\circ F(x,w)
\end{align}
is a continuous function of $x\in X$.

> I don't understand how Dominated convergence is applied here. I understand that $Ph(x) = E[h(F(x,w))]$ and $h\circ F(x,w)$ is bounded and continuous for each $w\in \mathbb{R}$. Normally, DCT is used to prove that a limit of integrals is equal to the integral of limits, so I'm not sure how DCT is applied here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Ph$ being bounded follows from $h$ being bounded and the integration being done on a finite measure space.

To see that $Ph$ is continuous, look at $\lim_{x \to x_0} Ph(x)$, then since $h$ is bounded, you see that the integrand is dominated by the integrable function $w \mapsto M$ where $M$ is a bound on $|h|$. So you can pass the limit inside by DCT and then use continuity of $h \circ F$.